# PHP Pear - Windows - pear command is not recognized (Environment variables are set)

Tags: php, pear

I try to install Pear i executed the file go-pear.bat and then the PEAR_ENV.reg to create the environment variables.

But when i type "pear" in DOS i got :
"Pear is not recognized as an internal or external command"

I saw that a number of people had the same issue because the environment variables were not set but it is for me, see the screenshot :

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to modify your `%PATH%` environment variable to include folder with `pear.bat`

Comment: Ok got it thank you :) with this: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/path.mspx?mfr=true